# Can we please include tags that represent health concerns for both genders? The female anatomy is almost non-existing in tags

Tags: discussion

I know  you have to earn enough reputation points to create "tags," and I do not have enough to do so, but I feel like there needs to be more options on tags before I have the authority/capacity to make it happen.

I find it a bit disconcerting that in this day in age that the female anatomy is pretty much completely ignored in the tag options available on the site. This is shameful and alarming since half the population are women, and these are real problems and concerns that woman deal with. Yes, it may be taboo or awkward to address these topics, but we need to get over it, so we can be more educated in regards to our own health (or health of any woman in your life).

For example: There is no tagging options for the following: ovary, vagina, cervix, uterus, PCOS, etc. Only until last week when another user raised a complaint that there wasn't a tag for "endometriosis" did someone finally add it for her. That's sad; it should have already been there.

Additionally, while the male anatomy is represented with the tag "penis," it would probably be worthwhile if there were tagging options for testicles and prostates.

And on a side note, unrelated to gender-specific tags, why don't we have tags for common general health issues: cysts, vertigo, White-Blood-Count, platelet levels, Lupus, etc.

I do understand that the medical field is vast and you can't create tag for each details or nuance out there, but basic general tags would be extremely helpful. I've noticed I had to tag some of my questions to other things that aren't really representative of my issue because the true topic did not exist as a tag (although it should have been).

I don't mean to come off as rude or a crazy feminist, but I think this would make it much more user-friendly -- for both the person asking the question and the person searching through questions to find answers because they would be better categorized.

I appreciate your consideration and hope that this feedback is helpful.

Comment: I agree. I have several questions I've been meaning to ask about my uterus, cervix, etc, but because the tags are not even available, I wasn't sure if it is even welcomed on this site. Questions regarding my "vagina" in the past were simply just put under "gynecology," which I think is too broad because the female anatomy is quite complex. It rubbed me the wrong way when I noticed that I couldn't type in "ovarian cyst" in for a tag -- neither words came up as a tag, which means I basically arbitrarily choose a tag. Tumors aren't cysts.

Comment: It was almost as if my health, or women's health in general, was of little concern to this community. I'm not sure that's the message you want to be sending out there.

Comment: @user51778 In addition to Susan's answer, a technical note: when you reach sufficient reputation to create tags have in mind that the system recognizes tags as single words, so if you want a tag that consists of multiple words, you have to use a dash (can't use space to separate them).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tags are created when people ask questions and apply them. In fact, if they are created without any questions, [they will be deleted automatically within 24h](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/101263/272257). So to OP's statement:

> That's sad; it should have already been there.

There's really no *should* here. It just means a relevant question has not yet been asked or, if the question was asked, the OP didn't have the privilege to create new tags or it didn't occur to them to do so. I don't find anything especially "shameful" or "alarming" about certain tags not existing.

It's true that [150 rep is required to have the privilege of creating new tags](https://health.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags). This should not be a barrier for the OP currently (*contra* the question). However, if anyone with <150 rep feels a tag should exist which does not, they have several options:

1. Leave a comment on the question stating that you think it warrants a particular tag. A higher rep user can edit it in for you.
2. Flag it with a mention that you would like such a tag added.
3. Bring it up on Meta as a specific request

Regardless of how you go about it, if the tag is appropriate I think you would have no problem achieving its creation.

Note that there's also no tag for [esophagus](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/esophagus) or [throat](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/throat) or [rectum](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rectum) or [shoulder](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shoulder). The site is young enough that not all organs or pathological states have come up yet. It may (or may not) be true that we have more questions here specific to male reproductive physiology/anatomy compared to female reproductive physiology/anatomy. If so, this likely reflects the fact that there are more men on the Stack Exchange network than there are women (source needed), or it may reflect the fact that men are more ignorant about their bodies and so need to ask questions. ;-) There's nothing inherently misogynistic about that.